# Passing an argument to map.js in a CouchApp view

Tags: couchdb, mapreduce, couchapp

I have a CouchApp that functions like a social network. I have a like button which, when clicked by a user, creates and saves a CouchDB JSON document with the fields post_id (the ID of the post that was liked), user_id (the ID of the user who liked the post), and type (value is "like," to indicate that the document is a like).

Alongside the post, I'd like to indicate the number of likes it has received. My map function looks like this:

```
function(doc) {
  if (doc.type && doc.type == 'like') {
    emit(doc.post_id, 1);
  }
}
```

and my reduce, this:

```
function(post_ids, likes) {
  return sum(likes);
}
```

My problem is, this function returns the sum of ALL the likes in ALL posts in the site. I'm thinking that my reduce.js is fine and that maybe I could tweak my map.js to accept a post_id argument so I can retrieve only the likes from that post_id, but how do I do that? The post_id comes from the design document, of course, when the "Like" button is clicked.

Thanks.

Comment: Okay, I just realized that there's something wrong with my objective. I should really just create another document that serves as a counter for the likes and the likers of a specific post. Sometimes the most difficult thing about CouchDB is when you're coming from relational databases like MySQL. You should really just change your frame of thought in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look into the [`group`](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Introduction_to_CouchDB_views#Grouping) view parameter. If you supply no querystring parameters, the default is to reduce the entire contents of the view. Once you apply `group=true`, you can also use `key` or `startkey/endkey` to pick out the post id(s) you need.

Also, there are [built-in reduce functions](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Built-In_Reduce_Functions) that can perform basic reduce operations much more efficiently. (since they are compiled erlang code, not javascript source) Just put `_count` in place of your entire `reduce.js`. (You can even leave off the `1` in your `emit`)